# Decelerate Car(Picturebox)

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Currently I am working on a game and I would like to have the car to slowly come to a complete stop instead of instant after letting go of the key. The current movement code is below.

```
Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short

Private Sub MovementTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MovementTimer.Tick

    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Up) <> 0 Then
        Car.Top -= 6
    End If
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Down) <> 0 Then
        Car.Top += 6
    End If
End Sub
```

What do I need to add or change to do so?

Comment: `WPF` and `Silverlight` have that functionality already built in.

Comment: @OneFineDay I already got a bit of code and I rather not convert to another application such as those two, also I am not very comfortable with coding in either of those yet.